# Scopus API call to provide the list of institutions within an hierarchy

Tags: scopus

I am using the Scopus API to extract publications linked to institutions.

The Scopus web interface provides two counts of papers for most institutions, "Documents Affiliation Only" and a larger number for "Documents Whole Institution".  There is also a tab which displays a list of affiliations linked to the parent.

I am needing an API call that will list the institutions within that hierarchy

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Scopus, you'll want to click on 'Affiliation Hierarchy' and find the top-level Affiliation ID.

Then, submit this ID through the affiliation profile retrieval API:

https://api.elsevier.com/content/affiliation/affiliation_id/xxxxxxxx?view=FULL

In this response, you'll find an identifier for a document containing the Affiliation Hierarchy:

> ```
> <hierarchy-document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
>     <eid>xx-xx.x-xxxxxxxx</eid>
> </hierarchy-document>
> ```

Take that  and submit it through the same profile retrieval API, using the 'eid' endpoint:

https://api.elsevier.com/content/affiliation/eid/xx-xx.x-xxxxxxxx?view=FULL

This response contains all the children to the top level hierarchy, which you can use to search, etc:

```
<institution-hierarchy verified="true">
        <institution xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" id="xxxxxxxx">
            <institution-name>xxxxxxxx</institution-name>
            <institution id="xxxxxxxx" rel-type="po">
                <institution-name>xxxxxxxx</institution-name>
                <institution id="xxxxxxxx" rel-type="po">
                    <institution-name>xxxxxxxx</institution-name>
                </institution>
                <institution id="xxxxxxxx" rel-type="po">
                    <institution-name>xxxxxxxx</institution-name>
                </institution>
                <institution id="xxxxxxxx" rel-type="po">
                    <institution-name>xxxxxxxx</institution-name>
                </institution>
                <institution id="xxxxxxxx" rel-type="po">
                    <institution-name>xxxxxxxx</institution-name>
```

...etc etc